# tvOS notification when TV's source/input/HDMI changed

Tags: input, notifications, avplayer, tvos, hdmi

So I have a video app for tvOS and I would like to serve ads on it, but one of the requirements is to not serve them while the TV is not showing them.

All good, but if you change the source of your TV and the Apple TV is still running it will continue to run and not lock or turn off while watching the videos. I thought that the resign active notification or entered background will give me that information, but they do not.

Is there any way to check if tvOS is currently on screen?

I am using tvOS 12 and AVPlayer.